# How did this person survive the Kharaa infection in Subnautica?

Tags: subnautica, subnautica-below-zero

In the original Subnautica, Marguerit is revealed to have been infected with Kharaa, along with the other members of the crash:

> BART: Please stop fighting and listen! We're sick!
>
> MARGUERIT: What?
>
> PAUL: How?
>
> BART: You've been coughing, right? Feeling itchy? Blisters?
>
> MARGUERIT: Yeah.

Later, Bart passes away due to the infection, and presumably Marguerit would have as well if she didn't -- seemingly -- die while fighting the reaper leviathan, since there was no cure at the time. However, in Below Zero, it's revealed that not only did Marguerit survive the reaper leviathan, but she had survived on Planet 4546B for 10 years before Ryley's arrival on the planet and the end of Kharaa, despite having the deadly infection.

Is it ever revealed how Marguerit survived such a fatal infection? Either in-game or out-of-game (e.g. developer commentary). In both games, Kharaa is built up as an extremely deadly bacteria that leads to inescapable death, so I'd be skeptical that Marguerit just luckily developed an immunity on her own. I haven't been able to find any PDAs in-game that provide an answer, and the [wiki](https://subnautica.fandom.com/wiki/Marguerit_Maida) is similarly devoid of any mention of her survival of Kharaa.